# Incorrect id retrieval

Tags: python, django, url, view, model

My project incorrect id retrieval.

My problem is that, my project take a project id, not a profile id. Any suggestions how i can solve this problem?

URLS

```
 path('profil_uzytkownika/<int:pk>/',ShowProfilPage.as_view(), name='profil_uzytkownika')
```

VIEWS

```
def MuzykaListView(request):
profils = Profil.objects.get(user=request.user)
muza = Muzyka.objects.all()

m = Muzyka.objects.all

template_name = 'Muzyka_List.html'
context = {
    'm':m,
    'profils':profils,
    'muza':muza,


}
return render(request, template_name, context)
```

MODELS

```
class Muzyka(models.Model):
nazwa_muzyki = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
opis_muzyki = models.TextField()
zdjecie_muzyki = models.ImageField(default='project_photo/default.jpg', upload_to="project_photo",blank= True, null=True,validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg','gif'])])
wlasciciel = models.ForeignKey(Profil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
opcja_nr1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="111-222-333", blank= True, null=True)
opcja_nr2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="TwojaNazwa@gmail.com", blank= True, null=True)
opcja_nr3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="www.TwojaNazwa.com", blank= True, null=True)
social_facebook_p = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank= True, null=True)
social_www_p = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank= True, null=True)
social_instagram_p = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank= True, null=True)
social_twitter_p = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank= True, null=True)
social_other_p = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank= True, null=True)
social_likedin_p = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank= True, null=True)
wybor_projekt = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=wybor_t_f, default="FALSZ")
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cykx5.png)

Comment: I have no idea what your actual question is...

Comment: My question is, why this take query number "8" when i have only 2 users, with id = 1 and id = 2.  I would like to be redirected to the user's profile after clicking on the username. I dont have idea how i can do this.